# How to modify the length of an underline

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, margins

I am trying to change the length of the underline under "Education".  I want to shorten the line (where it meets the far right redline) so that it is aligned with the red line on the left, so that the underline is perfectly aligned with everything down the leftmost red line. (Please see link below).

The underline seems to extend just a little too far where it isn't perfectly aligned with the right margin.

[image]

CODE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym} % font
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
% or \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in} 
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEd}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{p{0.8\linewidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemNoBullet}[2]{
    \vspace{-5pt}
    \item[]\small{
        \hspace{0pt}\textbf{#1} #2
        \vspace{-4pt}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-3pt}}


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{.99\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l} % originally .97\textwidth
  \textbf{\Huge John J. Doe} & Email: \href{mailto:johndoe@gmail.com}{johndoe@gmail.com}\\
  & Mobile: +1-312-312-3124 \\
  & Address: 000 E. South Water St.\\
  & \hspace{38.5pt} Chicago, IL. 60601
\end{tabular*}

%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheadingEd
      {Kellstadt Graduate School of Business -- DePaul University}{Chicago, IL}{Master of Science in Computational Finance}{November 2021}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the 1st tabular, use `\textwidth` to move `St.` a little bit to right and align it to the rule.

Comment: I don't want to move "St." over to the right, as I would have to move every single line in order for it to be aligned. I would rather just move the underline to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular `\rule` instead of `\textrule` when you format the section command, so can specify the width, but it's a bit of trial and error to get it to look right:

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-9pt}\color{black}\rule{0.99\textwidth}{0.4px} \vspace{-10pt}]
```

It wouldn't surprise me if there were a better way, but exactly why you're doing things the way you are now is a bit of mystery to me.

Comment: How should I be doing it, please explain?

Comment: I didn't have a particular alternative method, but what mainly seemed weird to me is choosing things like `0.97\textwidth` or `0.99\textwidth` for sizing certain things. Why not use the full width rather than something just off from that? Makes it all the more challenging to get things to match up.

Comment: Ah, noted. Yeah, I don't use LaTeX on a regular basis, and I haven't needed to update this resume for well over 2 years, so I can't tell you exactly why I did it like that at this very moment.  I'll play around with it, and use your suggestion. I just need to get familiar with how LaTeX works again.